# What is the equivalent function I should use for my query in OracleDB?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the where clause I current using in Mysql, I need to write this into Oracle with same logic.
The consprtydate column is in Timestamp(6) type.

```
WHERE ( ( rs.liferemaining <= 99999 ) 
   OR ( Abs(( Timestampdiff(hour, pk.consprtydate, rs.consprtydate) / 24 )) >= 1 ) )
```

Can any of your genius can help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `timestampdiff`, according to documentation, in your case returns number of hours between `pk.consprtydate` and `rs.consprtydate`.

Number of hours divided by 24 returns number of **days** between them.

So, why didn't you `timestampdiff(day, ...)` instead?

---

In Oracle, when you subtract two `DATE` datatype values, you get number of **days** between them. Therefore, that would be

```
or abs(pk.consprtydate - rs.consprtydate) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> The consprtydate column is in `Timestamp(6)` type.

Just add (or subtract) an `INTERVAL` literal:

```sql
WHERE (
      rs.liferemaining <= 99999
OR    pk.consprtydate <= rs.consprtydate - INTERVAL '1' DAY
OR    pk.consprtydate >= rs.consprtydate + INTERVAL '1' DAY
)
```

or use `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```sql
WHERE (
      rs.liferemaining <= 99999
OR    pk.consprtydate <= rs.consprtydate - INTERVAL '1' DAY
OR    ( GREATEST( pk.consprtydate, rs.consprtydate )
        - LEAST( pk.consprtydate, rs.consprtydate )
        >= INTERVAL '1' DAY )
)
```

or, you can convert the `TIMESTAMP(6)` values to a `DATE` and then subtract as, by default, this will give the difference in days (or fractions thereof):

```sql
WHERE (
      rs.liferemaining <= 99999
OR    ABS( CAST( pk.consprtydate AS DATE ) - CAST( rs.consprtydate AS DATE ) ) >= 1
)
```

*(However, if you care about fractional seconds then this last option might give some invalid responses when the `TIMESTAMP` value is truncated to a `DATE` and loses the fractional seconds.)*

Comment: Thank you, the first answer works for me. But still thank you very much my friend